# Initializing a class object inside another class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a group class which contains:

```
class Groups {   
protected $_db;
protected $member_id;
protected $group_id,$group_title;
public function __construct($db, $member_id) { 
    $this->_db = $db;
    $this->member_id = $member_id;
}
/** 
 * Set the group title
 *
 * @param str $group_id
 * 
 */
public function set_group_id($group_id) {
    $this->group_id = $group_id;    
}
/** 
 * Set the group id
 *
 * @param int $group_id
 * 
 */
public function get_group_id() {
    return $this->group_id; 
}
/** 
 * Set the group title
 *
 * @param str $group_id
 * 
 */
public function set_group_title($group_title) {
    $this->group_title = $group_title;  
}
/** 
 * get the group title
 *
 * @return int $group_id
 * 
 */
public function get_group_title() {
    return $this->group_title;
}
/** 
 * build existing group by id
 *
 * @param str $group_id
 * 
 */
public function fetch_group_by_id($group_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gps` WHERE `id` = ".sql_c($group_id)."
                    AND (`temp` != 'on' OR `temp` IS NULL)
                    AND (`backup` != 'on' OR `backup` IS NULL)";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql,$this->_db); check_sql(mysql_error(), $sql, 0);
    $list = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $this->set_group_id($list['id']);
    //set all group properties from this group
    $this->set_group_title($list['title']);
   }
}
```

Then I created an another class called group_value

I want to initialize my Group class inside this group_value class as follows, but when I tried It gives me unexpected error...

```
class Group_value extends Groups {
protected $_db;
protected $member_id;
protected $comment,
          $member_id,
          $group_id,
          $match,
          $match_id;    
function __construct($db, $member_id) {
    $this->_db = $db;
    $this->member_id = $member_id;
}

$groups = new Groups($db,$member_id); //HERE IT GIVES ME ERROR !! <<--
/** 
 * Set the comment
 *
 * @param str $comment
 * 
 */
public function set_comment($comment) {
    $this->comment = $comment;  
}                                                                     
}
```

To limit code repeating I would like to include the Groups class inside the Group_value

Answer (score 0):

Move `$groups = new Groups($db,$member_id);` into constructor:

```
function __construct($db, $member_id) {
    parent::__construct($db, $member_id);

    $this->groups = new Groups($db,$member_id);
}
```

And also define it as protected variable.

**EDIT:** changed to call parent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

use `parrent::` to call `protected` or `public` properties or methods from `Groups` into `Group_value` since `Group_value` is extending `Groups`

Also in the `__construct` of `Group_value` you need to call the parents' `__construct` like this  `parent::__construct();`